# Stove burner on indicator light still on?

Tags: oven, stove-top

I have a simple 5 year old stove with 4 burners. Recently the light came on while cooking (burner sensor light), but has yet to turn off. It's an electric stove.

Is the light broken and needs repair? Or is there something worse happening (electricity is still being fed but the burners don't heat up?).

What are the first ways to start figuring out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lights are driven by thermostat switches in the glass top surface. Sometimes there is only one, sometimes there is one for each burner. You'll need to open the stove to figure out what kind you have, and then disconnect them one by one to figure out which one is stick. From there you should be able to order a replacement.